# Can't install gosu gem

Tags: ruby, game-development, libgosu

I am trying to install gosu gem using docker but I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/gosu-1.4.5/lib/gosu.so: warning: undefining the allocator of T_DATA class swig_runtime_data
/usr/local/bundle/gems/gosu-1.4.5/lib/gosu/swig_patches.rb:18:in `initialize': Could not initialize SDL Video: No available video device (RuntimeError)
```

I have tried modifying the dockerfile or installing additional libraries
For example:

ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp

or

apt install xorg-dev

Here is my Dockerfile

```
from ruby:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -qq -y install curl && apt-get install -y build-essential libsdl2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libopenal-dev libgmp-dev libfontconfig1-dev xorg-dev && gem install gosu
ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp

EXPOSE 3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the SDL library to display graphics. Add this to docker file,

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsdl2-dev
RUN gem install gosu
```

Refer this for the set of libraries to be further added for docker if the above command don't solve the issue. [unable to install Gosu library in Ruby in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466834/unable-to-install-gosu-library-in-ruby-in-linux) .